# how can i enter multiple dropdown option into single database filed?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<select name"nom[]" id="nom" multiple >
    <option value="BlackTrap">Blacktrap</option>
    <option value="Murrum">Murrum</option>
    <option value="Odinary Clay">Ordinary Clay </option>
    <option value="Lignite">Lignite</option>
    <option value="Odinary Send">Ordinary Send</option>
    <option value="Limestone">Limestone</option>
    <option value="Earth Bricks">Earth Bricks</option>
    <option value="Greval">Greval</option>
    <option value="Silica Sand">Silica Sand</option>
    <option value="Hard moroum">Hard moroum</option>
    <option value="Dolo Might">Dolo Might</option>
    <option value="None">None</option>
</select>
```

And the below code is of php.

```
class PDF extends FPDF
  {
  // Page header
  function Header()
  {

    //$ID = $_POST['ID'];

      // Logo
      $this->Image('logo.jpg',25,10,175);
      // Arial bold 12
      $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);

      $this->Cell(100,80,'No/GS/'.$_POST["Reg"].'/'.$_POST["no"].'/'.$GLOBALS['last_id'],0,0,'C');  $this->Cell(150,80,'Dt.'. date("d/m/Y"),0,0,'C');

      $this->Ln(5);
      $this->Cell(200,100,'Registration for Grant of registrantion',0,0,'C');

      // Line break
      $this->Ln(60);
  }

  // Page footer
  function Footer()
  {
      // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
      $this->SetY(-12);
      // Arial italic 8
      $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
      // Page number
      $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
  }
  }

  // Instanciation of inherited class
  $pdf = new PDF();

  $pdf->AliasNbPages();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',14);
  $pdf->SetX(30);
  //$pdf->Cell(25,12,'Registration: '.$_POST["Reg"],0,1);
  //$pdf->Cell(25,12,'Nomber: '.$_POST["no"],0,1);

    $pdf->Cell(25,12,'Name Of Applicant: '.$_POST["name"],0,1);
      $pdf->SetX(30);
    $pdf->Cell(25,12,'Address: '.$_POST["add"],0,1);
      $pdf->SetX(30);
    $pdf->Cell(25,12,'Name of Mineral/ore: '.$_POST["nom"],0,1);
      $pdf->SetX(30);
    $pdf->Cell(25,12,'Place of Storage: '.$_POST["Storage"],0,1);
      $pdf->SetX(30);
    $pdf->Cell(25,12,'Date of Registration From : '.$_POST["Date1"],0,1);
      $pdf->SetX(30);
    $pdf->Cell(25,12,'Date of Registration To: '.$_POST["Date2"],0,1);
      $pdf->SetX(30);
    $pdf->Cell(25,12,'Profession of the registrant : '.$_POST["Profession"],0,1);
      $pdf->SetX(30);
    $pdf->Cell(50,12,'Remark: '.$_POST["remark"],0,1);
    $pdf->Output();

}
}
}
```

i get this to error while executing the code

> Notice: Undefined index: nom in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MinesMineral_v3/final/connection.php on line 558
>
> Notice: Undefined index: nom in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MinesMineral_v3/final/connection.php on line 616
>   FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Comment: assuming you are trying to store the selected result into a single field, you would have to put it into some organized form csv, json, xml, etc

Comment: The real question is HOW Do you want to see it in the report?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `name` attribute must be

```
name="nom[]" // not name"nom[]"
```

That's why you get your `undefined index` warning.

Second, as `$_POST["nom"]` is array, to get the string representation of it, you should use for example, `implode`:

```
$pdf->Cell(25,12,'Name of Mineral/ore: '.implode(', ', $_POST["nom"]),0,1);
```

In this case you will have list of items divided by `,`.

Or you can iterate over `$_POST["nom"]` and output each item in each `Cell` call:

```
foreach ($_POST["nom"] as $ore) {
    $pdf->Cell(25,12,'Name of Mineral/ore: ' . $ore,0,1);
}
```